# How does hideexpression work with custom validation?

Tags: angular-formly

I have fieldGroup with hideexpression and a field with custom validation in this field group. First time the expression hide the fieldgroup and it will be visible after I push a button. My problem is custom validator does not trigger if hideexpression hided the fieldgroup earlier. The field is visible after pushed button but validator does not work. If I set hideexpression to false in initialization (so never hide group) then validator works well. I experienced this with custom validation. Required validation works well.

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible example of your issue on https://codesandbox.io/. This will allow the community to better understand the specific challenges you're facing and offer more targeted assistance.